# Adding custom templates to VS (2015) Isolated Shell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've created a VS 2015 Isolated Shell application to be used for just a few process-specific tasks.  I have successfully created the templates of the classes that would be used for these tasks, however I am unable to add these templates to the shell application.  I've exported the project template and added to the manifest, yet the templates do not show up when I run the shell.  I'm thinking this may be a configuration issue - pkgdef maybe? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks